# Basic authentication to squid proxy is not working using java

Tags: java, basic-authentication, http-proxy, squid, jira-rest-java-api

I  have configured basic authentication on my Ubuntu virtual machine running remotely. I have the following curl command that works fine when I run it in the terminal:

```
curl -v -x http://username:password@10.0.114.4:3128 https://www.google.com/
```

If I remove the authentication from it, it responds with an authentication error. When I write Java code for the same purpose, it does not go well and it always returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.createTunnel(RealConnection.java:320)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildTunneledConnection(RealConnection.java:155)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:193)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
    at SendEmailClass.getIssueDetails(SendEmailClass.java:239)
    at SendEmailClass.searchIssuesAndSendEmail(SendEmailClass.java:63)
    at SendEmailClass.main(SendEmailClass.java:59)
```

Here is my Java code that makes a call to the proxy and then to the other required server:

```
    private static Issues[] getIssueDetails(String jql) throws IOException {
        String url = SERVER_URL + "rest/api/3/search?jql=" + jql;
        System.out.println(url);

        BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();

        System.out.println("Proxy provided details are as follows| Username: " + proxyUsername + " Password: " + proxyPassword + " Port: " + proxyPort + " Address: " + proxyHost);

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        String authHeader = getAuthHeader();
        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", authHeader);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        int response_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        try {
            if (response_code != 400) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                CloudIssueDetailResponse cloudIssueDetailResponse = gson.fromJson(responseBody, CloudIssueDetailResponse.class);
                return cloudIssueDetailResponse.getIssues();
            } else {
                System.err.println("Authentication failed using the following credentials: Email: " + EMAIL + " API Key: " + API_KEY);
            }
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

What might be causing the issue? I can confirm that the proxy and the 2nd server details are correct in the code.